# Why `npm install jquery` does nothing?

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

I did `npm install jquery` in an empty directory and no files appeared inside. Why? Should they appear?

Transcript follows:

```
D:\Users\Dims\Design\TESTS\NodeJs\yarn01>dir

D:\Users\Dims\Design\TESTS\NodeJs\yarn01>npm install jquery
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Users\Dims\Design\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Users\Dims\Design\package.json'
npm WARN Design No description
npm WARN Design No repository field.
npm WARN Design No README data
npm WARN Design No license field.

+ jquery@3.5.1
updated 1 package and audited 263 packages in 1.334s
found 132 vulnerabilities (30 low, 58 moderate, 44 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

D:\Users\Dims\Design\TESTS\NodeJs\yarn01>dir

D:\Users\Dims\Design\TESTS\NodeJs\yarn01>
```

Comment: Have you first initialized your project with `npm init`?

Comment: It would appear that `npm install jquery` does something, rather than nothing :). It just does something you didn't expect. The way npm works is, it will search for a package.json file in the path and try to use it if found. Apparently, it found one in D:\Users\Dims\Design, and it already had jQuery installed. AFAIK, you need to run `npm install jquery` in a folder separate from any folder that may already contain a package.json.